# Checking compatible total orders given by a Python list

Tags: python, list, compatibility

I'm using the [IPython shell](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/) here.

Suppose I have two lists

```
In [1]: L1 = [1,3,4,5,2]

In [2]: L2 = [1,3,5,5,1]
```

I'd like to say that `L1` and `L2` are compatible in the sense that the ordering generated by the *indices* of the increasing order of the elements are compatible.

That is, `L1` gives 0<4<1<2<3 while `L2` gives {0,4}<1<{2,3}.  (If stackoverflow accepted jsmath or MathJax, this would be easier, my apologies.)

Edit: As pointed out below, this is not exactly checking whether two given elements are < or <= in both of these.  I like @Cosmologicon's example that `[1,2]` and `[1,1]` are compatible, as are `[1,1]` and `[2,1]`, but `[2,1]` and `[1,2]` are not.  I hope this clarifies what I mean.

So I'd like a way to take two lists and check that the (not necessarily strict) total orders given by those two lists are compatible like this.  Here is an example where they are not.

```
In [3]: L3 = [1,2,3,4,5]

In [4]: L4 = [1,2,4,2,5]
```

I hope it is clear the order given by `L3` is 0<1<2<3<4; the order given by `L4` is 0<{1,3}<2<4, and the incompatibility is that while 1<=3 in both orders, 2<3 in one of the while 3<2 in the other.

Another, harder, example is whether `[1,3,5,5,1]` and `[1,2,2,3,2]` are compatible.  The non-strict total orders are {0,4}<1<{2,3} and 0<{1,2,4}<3

It would suffice for my purposes to restrict to the case where the biggest number is always `len(list1)` and the only possible values are integers from `1` to `len(list1)` *and* where `list1` always is some permutation of that set of integers, but naturally I wouldn't complain if someone found something more general.   Thanks very much in advance!

Disclaimer from a first-time poster:  This is *not* a question about sorting :)  I did do quite a bit of searching for this, but really only found more programming-type questions, which are nearly always about sorting or comparing values; this is a little more subtle.  In fact, it's really a mathematical application, so it may not seem as 'useful' to many folks here, though it will be quite useful to me.  At any rate, it's beyond my current skill level to hack this out very quickly, though I hope someday it will be 'obvious' to me.  I don't think there is anything in itertools for this, either, though I'd love to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> That is, L1 gives 0<4<1<2<3 while L2 gives 0<=4<1<2<=3. One can see that if two of these
>   indices are <= each other in one list, that is true in both lists.

Sorry, your definition given here of compatible doesn't match your example. In L2, 4<=0, but the same is not true in L1. I suspect the definition you meant to give is: if a<b in one list, then a<=b in the other list.

In that case, none of the previous solutions work. L1 = [1,1] and L2 = [2,1] should be compatible.

Any solution would need to realize that compatibility is not transitive. For instance, if L1 = [1,2], L2 = [1,1], and L3 = [2,1], then L1 is compatible with L2 and L2 is compatible with L3, but L1 is not compatible with L3. So any solution that checks for equality between some "orderings" computed from the lists will fail.

Thiago Chaves's solution doesn't have this problem, but it fails on L1 = [2,2,1], L2 = [2,1,1]. These should be compatible.

EDIT: If efficiency is not a huge concern, here's a quick O(N^2) solution that simply tests each pair of numbers:

```
def compat5(L1, L2):
    z = zip(L1, L2)
    return not any(j1<k1 and j2>k2 for j1,j2 in z for k1,k2 in z)
```

Comment: Yes, you're correct about the transitivity problem.  [1,1] and [2,1] should be compatible.  I feel like there is something missing after "if a" in your answer.  Anyway, I'm updating the question based on Shang's as well.

Comment: Sorry about the typo. It should have been "a<b", not "a - newline - b". I didn't realize the formatting had changed it.

Comment: It's not efficient, you are right!  But doing some `timeit`s on typical use cases for me tells me it's probably not going to add appreciably to the time of the thing that _generates_ these lists in the first place :)

Comment: I suspect that this is a hard problem, and a solution in the general case will have to be O(N^2) anyway. But of course if someone comes up with a faster one, might as well go with it! Just make sure you test it well. The O(N) solution that pillmuncher just gave fails for [2,1], [1,1], plus a few other inputs I tried.

Comment: I was just trying to figure out his code too, and suspected something like that might happen.  I think one really will have to use all pairs for a naive one.  Could one combine his use of itertools and yours to speed it up slightly?

Comment: It's worth a shot, but I wouldn't hope for much. Using iterators rather than building lists (as I did) generally tend to give you a smaller memory footprint, but negligible speed improvements. How big are your lists anyway? My code could also be modified so you're not testing elements against themselves, but this would give a very slight speedup at best.

Comment: You're right - and as I said, we're talking timings on the order of around 200 microseconds for my current use cases.  (Hopefully I'll start getting into lists of length growing on a factorial basis, but again I don't think this part will be the slowdown.)

Comment: Sorry no one upvoted your answer, but it is what I needed.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Part of the way there would be to generate a list of tuples of list-elements and indexes, I think. This can then be sorted by list-element value and the index extracted.

Something like:

```
L1order = [t[1] for t in sorted(zip(L1, range(len(L1))))]
L2order = [t[1] for t in sorted(zip(L2, range(len(L2))))]
L1order == L2order
```

Turning this into a function should be trivial.

Comment: @DSM Is this the DSM I think it is?

Comment: @DSM: Thanks, copy&paste is a dangerous beast.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure if this is what you are after, but it works for the examples you have provided:

```
import operator

def compatible(l1,l2):
    return ordered_indices(l1) == ordered_indices(l2)

def ordered_indices(l):
    tmp = list(enumerate(l))
    tmp.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    return map(operator.itemgetter(0), tmp)
```

```
>>> compatible([1,3,4,5,2], [1,3,5,5,1])
True
>>> compatible([1,2,3,4,5], [1,2,4,2,5])
False
```

Updated version:

```
import operator, itertools

def compatible(l1,l2):
    if len(l1) != len(l2): return False
    i1 = ordered_indices(l1)
    i2 = ordered_indices(l2)
    g1 = None
    g2 = None
    while i1 and i2:
        g1 = g1 or i1.pop(0)
        g2 = g2 or i2.pop(0)
        if len(g1) > len(g2):
            g1,g2 = g2,g1
            i1,i2 = i2,i1
        x = g1.pop()
        if x not in g2:
            return False
        g2.remove(x)
    return True


def ordered_indices(l):
    tmp = list(enumerate(l))
    value = operator.itemgetter(1)
    index = operator.itemgetter(0)
    tmp.sort(key=value)
    groups = itertools.groupby(tmp, value)
    return [set(map(index, g)) for k, g in groups]
```

```
>>> compatible([1,3,5,5,1],[1,2,2,3,2])
True
```

Comment: That's a good try!  Thank you.  Unfortunately it doesn't work for `compatible([1,3,5,5,1],[1,2,2,3,2])`, which ought to return `True`.  I'll update the question to point this out.

Comment: @kcrisman: Ah ok, I didn't understand the original problem properly. I've updated my solution.

Answer (score 1):

I did the following expanding on shang's answer. It takes into consideration the special fact involved when two values are the same. Simply ordering the lists and comparing them could give the wrong result. For example, if the order in list 1 is 0 < 1 < 2 and the order in list 2 is 0 < 1 <= 2, ordering the second list could give as result both [0,1,2] and [0,2,1], and in this last case, shang's method would fail. This depends on the behavior of the sorting routine.

```
import operator

def order_indexes(l):
    tmp = list(enumerate(l))
    tmp.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1))
    return map(operator.itemgetter(0), tmp)

def are_compatible(l1, l2):
    # Order one list, retaining the indexes
    ordered = order_indexes(l1)
    # For each pair of indexes on the list
    for i in xrange(len(ordered) - 1):
        pair = (ordered[i], ordered[i + 1])
        # See if the pairs in the other list are compatible
        # If a1 <= b1 then a2 must be <= b2 
        if l2[pair[0]] > l2[pair[1]]:
            return False
    # If all pairs are compatible, then the lists are compatible
    return True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    l1 = [1,3,4,5,2]
    l2 = [1,3,5,5,1]
    l3 = [1,2,3,4,5]
    l4 = [1,2,4,2,5]
    print "L1 X L2 ",are_compatible(l1, l2)
    print "L2 X L1 ",are_compatible(l2, l1)
    print "L3 X L4 ",are_compatible(l3, l4)
    print "L4 X L3 ",are_compatible(l4, l3)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible algorithm is as follows:

```
def compatible
    temp1=L1[:]
    temp2=L2[:]
    max1=max(L1)+1
    max2=max(L2)+2
    order1=[]
    for i in range(len(L1)):
        pos=t1.index(min(t1))
        order1.append(pos)
        t1[pos]=max1
    for i in range(len(L2)):
        pos=t2.index(min(t2))
        order2.append(pos)
        t2[pos]=max2
    return order1==order2
```

This algorithm relies on the members of each list being unequal. If you want to use lists with duplicates, you would need to keep track of the pairs that are equal and check whether switching any of the pairs would make the orderings the same.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]
Ok, I'm stupid. It can be made even simpler, obviously:

```
def compatible_ordering(xs, ys):
    return all(
        y1 <= y2
            for (_, y1), (_, y2) in pairwise(sorted(izip(xs, ys)))
    )
```

[/EDIT]

Here's an O(n * log n) solution:

```
from itertools import izip, tee

def pairwise(iterable):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b)
    return izip(a, b)

def compatible_ordering(xs, ys):
    return all(
        x1 == x2 or y1 <= y2
            for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in pairwise(sorted(izip(xs, ys)))
    )
```

It's basically a one liner, if you don't count the [`pairwise()` recipe from itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes). Man, you gotta love Python for this.

BTW, notice the similarity to the wrong solution at the end.

How it works can probably be easier explained if we rewrite the algorithm into a more procedural form:

```
def compatible_ordering(xs, ys):             # line 0
    xys = zip(xs, ys)                        # line 1
    xys.sort()                               # line 2
    for (x1, y1), (x2, y2) in pairwise(xys): # line 3
        if x1 < x2 and y1 > y2:              # line 4
            return False                     # line 5
    return True                              # line 6
```

This time we don't try to find out if a condition holds for all elements ( = *success*), but instead if a condition holds for some element ( = *failure*), so the testing formula is basically negated.

Now, for every pair of neighbouring tuples `((x1, y1), (x2, y2))`:

- Always `x1 <= x2`, since we sorted them that way. That implies that if `x1 != x2` then `x1 < x2`.
- If `x1 == x2` we know that `y1 <= y2`, again because we sorted them so.
- If `x1 < x2` and `y1 <= y2`, both `(x1, x2)` and `(y1, y2)` have the same ordering and we continue.
- Otherwise if `x1 < x2` and `y1 > y2`, our two lists have incompatible orderings and we `return False`.
- If we're done iterating and haven't found any incompatibility, we `return True`.

IOW: the sorting creates an ordering for `ys` defined by `xs`, and by `ys`itself for equal elements in `xs` (since equal elements of `xs` don't impose any ordering on `ys`). Then all we have to do is to test if `ys` is indeed ordered.

Here's an example. After line 0 we have e.g.:

```
xs == [4, 3, 4, 2, 5, 4, 0, 2, 0, 5]
ys == [4, 1, 5, 1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 1, 3]
```

In line 2 we zip those and get:

```
xys == [(4, 4), (3, 1), (4, 5), (2, 1), (5, 5), (4, 5), (0, 2), (2, 2), (0, 1), (5, 3)]
```

In line 3 we sort:

```
xys == [(0, 1), (0, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 5), (5, 3), (5, 5)]
```

In line 4 we iterate through all pairs of neighbouring tuples of the sorted list and test in line 5:

```
  x1  y1     x2  y2       x1     x2      y1    y2
( 0 , 1 ), ( 0 , 2 )  -->  0  <  0  and  1  >  2   -->  False  -->  continue
( 0 , 2 ), ( 2 , 1 )  -->  0  <  2  and  2  >  1   -->  True   -->  return False
```

BTW #2: It's very possible that this version is faster then the oneliner.

[EDIT]

The following was my first and *WRONG* answer to the OP's question. Still, I don't delete it, as an example to what happens if you post without reading carefully.

Here's an O(n) solution:

```
def compatible_ordering(xs, ys):
    return all(
        (x1 <= x2) == (y1 <= y2)
            for (x1, x2), (y1, y2) in izip(pairwise(xs), pairwise(ys))
    )
```

Comment: With the new definition I still get discrepancies between this and @Cosmologicon's with a fairly high percentage (3%?) of false positives by yours.  E.g. [4, 3, 4, 2, 5, 4, 0, 2, 0, 5] and [4, 1, 5, 1, 5, 5, 2, 2, 1, 3], where the first and last entries are in the opposite order.

Comment: No problem on the posting quickly - it's still very informative and helpful to me!  You are very right that you gotta love Python for so many reasons.  There are several answers here I'd upvote, but I don't have the rep :)

Comment: This seems to work, though I'm still not quite sure why.  But amazingly, timeit shows that compat5 is about 5% faster on my machine.

Comment: I re-wrote the explanation on how the algorithm works. I hope this is better than the last one, which was a little terse.

Comment: Thanks for the *very* detailed explanation - more than I needed, but a great example, because a lot of times things are too terse in programming guides.  As for my question, what I didn't realize what that the `sorted` would sort by `xs` first, then `ys`, so it was mystifying why you had used that - but it makes sense now.  I suppose that the call to `sort` is what makes this about as fast as the other one.

Comment: To reiterate: *Ok, I'm stupid. It can be made even simpler, obviously.*

Comment: I hope you didn't take offense; I'm the one who felt stupid that I didn't understand why your (2nd) code worked!  And like I said, more detail is better in my opinion on a site for helping people find information.  No worries.  Someday I will have enough rep to upvote both answers that ended up correct :)

Comment: Nah! I felt offended by myself for not recognizing the implications of my own words. I wrote: _the sorting creates an ordering for ys defined by xs, and by ys itself for equal elements in xs (since equal elements of xs don't impose any ordering on ys). Then all we have to do is to test if ys is indeed ordered_. That means we only have to test if `y1 <= y2`, not if `x1 == x2 or y1 <= y2`.